# Eclipse Tomcat integration: useBean class attribute [class] is invalid

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, javabeans

I'm using Eclipse Juno (Java EE) and Tomcat 7.0. I've successfully connected Tomcat and Eclipse with this tutorial: http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-eclipse

JSTL and *.jsp files are working well within Eclipse and Tomcat but I can't use JavaBeans.

I store my JavaBeans in /WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/com/form.

In the *.jsp File (which is in /WebContent)  I use the following code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page import="com.form.*" %>
...
<jsp:useBean id="input" class="com.form.Input"/>
```

Input.java:

```
package com.form;

public class Input {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String gender;

    private boolean vegetarian;

    public Input() {
        this.firstName = new String();
        this.lastName = new String();
        this.gender = new String();
    }
...
```

When I run this application I get the following error message:

```
The value for the useBean class attribute com.form.Input is invalid
```

I don't want to post the whole code but you can download the complete Eclipse project here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6454333/BeanForm.zip

I hope you can help me.

Thank you and good bye

konze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing source files and class files.

`WebContent` is the place, in Eclipse, where you put the resources of the webapp (html files, images, css files, jsp files, etc.). There shouldn't be anything under `WebContent/WEB-INF/classes`. No `.java` file. No `.class` file.

When building the application with Eclipse, Eclipse will compile all the `.java` files in the project source directory, and the generated `.class` files will be part of the runtime classpath of the deployed web application.

If you generate a war file from eclipse, it will contain a WEB-INF/classes directory which will contain the .class file it has generated when compiling the source files from the project source directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Which one is the source directory? And how can I use the Bean after I stored it in the source directory?

Comment: [SOLVED]: to create a new JavaBean: click right on the Project -> New -> Class. Then type a package name and a class name. Press finish. Then you can use the bean inside of your *.jsp files (see first post).